# Using sql field in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, mysql, custom-component

I have a custom component, it allows admins to select a related content article from the #__content table using the following:

```
<field name="relatedcontent" type="sql" default="10" label="Related item" 
    sql_select="e.*" 
    sql_from="#__content AS e" 
    sql_group="title" 
    sql_order="e.title ASC" 
    key_field="id" 
    value_field="title" 
    header="Please select your option"/>
```

This then allows me to show in the frontend as follows:

```
$id_one = $this->item->interested_in_one;
<a href="<?php echo JRoute::_('index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=' . $id_one); ?>">
```

This gets the ID of the selected content article and creates the URL accordingly from above.

I need to further extend this by:

- getting the alias (of the content article) in the URL
- stop Joomla from adding '&Itemid=101' to the end of the URL, or at least load the correct one